# What is data range expression protege?

Tags: ontology, protege

May question is a bit basic. But I do not know what happens when we define "data range expressions" in protege? Does it limit the range only to the literals written there?
In what cases can we use "data range expressions?"

Below is an example that I saw in an [ontology](https://icdd.vm.rub.de/ontology/bcom/#normativereference):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  semantics of data property domains and ranges are given by
[image: domain and range semantics]

which you can find defined in the direct semantics of [OWL 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-direct-semantics/).

This means that for every 2 individuals `x` and `y` that  are related by a data property `DPE`,  that `x` is of type `CE` and `y` is of type `DR`.

In your example it means that if `x` and `y` are related via `test type` then the reasoner will infer `x` is of type `Concrete placement OR Test` and `y` is of type `{"Self-inspection", "Third-Party Monitoring"}`.

**Update based on comment**

This means that if individual `y` does **not** have the value of either `"Self-inspection"` OR `"Third-Party Monitoring"`, it will result in the ontology being inconsistent.

So, yes, the user has to choose between these 2 values.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. Normally, when I use protege, I set the `y` to Literal or float and so on. But in this case, it is already predefined `{"Self-inspection", "Third-Party Monitoring"}`... does it mean that the users of the ontology have to choose between these two options and cannot enter any data on their own for `y`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can I ask why did they not model `"Self-inspection" and "Third-Party Monitoring"` as classes? would that be ontologically wrong? (I know that you are not the person responsible for this decision, but I am curious to understand if that would be a wrong way to model an ontology)

Comment: Considerations wrt modelling something as an individual/value vs class are numerous: 1. Can it have members? If yes, then use class else use individual. 2. Use cases - For some use cases individuals may be more intuitive than classes or vice versa. 3. In DL there is much more sophistication as to what can be said about classes than individuals - therefore classes may be more prevalent. 4. Some communities prefer using individuals, i.e. SKOS extensively use individuals and very few classes. This is typically the case where reasoning is not used. Etc....